# Syncing with Swift Package Manager in AppCode fails: attempt to write a readonly database

Tags: appcode

With AppCode `2020.3`, "syncing" my XCode projects fails. I only got the following error message, which says "attempt to write a readonly database":

```
Package manifest execution failed with exit code 1:
/Users/username/Library/Caches/JetBrains/AppCode2020.3/DerivedData/APPNAME-dipqgziskjyufxhbqzlvojhifwse/SourcePackages/checkouts/Leanplum-iOS-SDK: error: error: accessing build database "/Users/username/Library/Caches/JetBrains/AppCode2020.3/DerivedData/APPNAME-dipqgziskjyufxhbqzlvojhifwse/SourcePackages/checkouts/Leanplum-iOS-SDK/.build/manifest.db": attempt to write a readonly database
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by changing enabling adding write permissions:

```
chmod 774 /Users/username/Library/Caches/JetBrains/AppCode2020.3/DerivedData/APPNAME-dipqgziskjyufxhbqzlvojhifwse/SourcePackages/checkouts/Leanplum-iOS-SDK/.build/manifest.db
```

More details: I needed to add permissions to the users in the files "group" (`staff`).

I have posted this as a bug report on [youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-21233), as this does not happen in XCode.